# How to consume messages from RBMQ queue using b-rabbit library

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to consume RBMQ messages.
Actually I was using pika library but it is not thread safe.

So I am going to use [b-rabbit](https://pypi.org/project/b-rabbit/) library.
But in the library doc, it is mentioned about only publishing messages to queue.

It is for only publishing messages?

I need to consume messages and ack the queue.
Anyone can help me? thanks

Comment: 1. in the first page of readme of b-rabbit: you have EventPublisher and EventSubscriber. EventSubscriber is the one that reads a message from a topic. 
2. pika is not thread safe when used incorrectly. If a connection is open in a context of a thread (and not shared), then it is safe to use. 
Reading documentation helps with these matters

Comment: @Fnaxiom  thanks for your reply. Could you possibly give me some example code for pika thread safe?